# multiple class inheritance implication

Tags: inheritance

I know the diamonds problem is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If there is a method in A that B and C have overridden, and D does not override it, then which version of the method does D inherit: that of B, or that of C

But why do we need to have this length explanation, can we just say B and C have a same method, and D inherits B and C, there is no such a method in D, so when we create a instance of D and call the method, the compiler wouldn't know which version of the method does D inherit. So we can avoid mentioning class A and transfer the diamond problem to "triangle problem"?

Comment: And why is this tagged as c#?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I think you're saying you expect the compiler to reject `d->foo()` as ambiguous between `B::foo()` and `C::foo()`, and (in some languages) that is indeed what happens.  (Note that the diamond 'problem' is usually about whether or not `D` should contain multiple copies of `A`'s data, not method resolution.)