# delegate has to be before main ?method

Tags: c#, delegates

Let say I have a Student class

```
class Program
{
   delegate bool del2(Student s); //I have to put this delegate before Main?
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      List<Student> listStudent = new List<Student>()
      {
         ... //adding student instances...
      };
      //delegate bool del2(Student s); Q1: why compile error if I put it here?
      Predicate<Student> del1 = check;
      Student s = listStudent.Find(del1);
      Console.WriteLine("s is" + s.Name);
   }
   public static bool check(Student s) //Q2:why it need to be static method? 
   {
      return s.Name == "Michael";
   }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why I have to put del2 before the main method? del1 is a Predicate delegate, I can put it inside the main method, del2 is also a delegate, why I can't put it inside the main method too?
2. Why the check method has to be static?

Comment: It is a type declaration.  Just like a struct or class declaration.  C# syntax demands that type declarations do not appear inside a method body.  Moving it *after* the Main() method is fine as well, just not inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

You should declare delegate and Predicate as it is done in the MSDN documents, because off course you should.

Long Answer:

1. You don't have to put that delegate before Main. You just can't put it inside Main. This is a type declaration. And that type(Delegate with certain signature you declared) is meant to be used for passing functions as parameters. Things you declare in main, or any other method will be valid just in that method's scope. Even if you could declare a delegate in a method, the signature would not be defined( and recognizable) at anywhere else and this would be useless.
2. Actually the method you assigned to a Predicate doesn't have to be static, it just have to be there when you assign it. Static functions are available without creating an instance of their class. They are independent of objects of that class. Non-static methods belong to their objects and they are specific to their objects. Their specific object code is created with object creation. So you can use a non-static function, if an available object has it. Say Student class have a non-static check method. You can do this:

   ```
   Student s2= new Student();
   Predicate<Student> del1 = s2.check;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so clear. Could you also answer this question for me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404219/multiple-class-inheritance-implication